# ATI graphics card detected but not used on Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, amd-graphics, amdgpu, gpu-driver

I have an IBM T43 laptop with an ATI X300 graphics card running **L**ubuntu 18.04 with latest updates.

The graphics card [is fully supported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Fully_supported), is listed in the *System Profiler and Benchmark* app and `lspci | grep VGA` outputs:

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV370/M22 [Mobility Radeon X300]

But `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"` outputs:

> OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 128 bits)

It was working properly before upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04. I've purged and reinstalled Xserver but it didn't help.

It'd be great to use the video card to spare the old Pentium M that can still write this post. Any ideas on how to tackle this?